# Is pinging someone for more info via @ in a comment considered bad practice?

Tags: discussion, comments

Couldn't find if this has been addressed.

Circumstance: a comment containing generic, but relevant info was made by SomeArbitraryUser.

As normal, several answers with multiple comments post. A few weeks go by, then an answer or comment triggers my interest in hearing more about that earlier generic comment.

However, the commentator, SomeArbitraryUser has likely moved on, because his comment was made in passing and he has not posted anymore comments or answers. So, knowing that "Bumping" is considered bad practice elsewhere, and this may seem similar, is it OK to ping that user with something like:

" @ SomeArbitraryUser could you please post more information or links to item mentioned in your comment previously. "

To me, this seems OK because it asks to *add* more content and clarification to the thread - it isn't just 'bumping' per se.  (Just asking to make sure :))

Comment: if its like `please post more information or links to item mentioned in your comment previously.` than its ok but if its like `can you give me code` is quite bad

Comment: @NullPoiиteя yes - I absolutely agree with that. (Maybe we need a "gimme code" flag ? LOL )

Comment: Is this one of your questions, or someone else's question? It it is yours maybe you also want to add the request to the question?

Comment: Oh how much I want to change my display name to "SomeArbitraryUser"... ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber you can't, I've already trademarked it and all variants ;-P iArbitraryUser, TheArbitraryUser, and of course, the long-sought after SomeArbitraryAlfredENeuman

Comment: @user814064 in this case, it was a response under someone else's OP. I provided an answer and later realized that comment, if fleshed out, could contribute to both the OP's question and my answer. (That's why I thought it OK to "ping with request for more info" Good, you all say it's ok - with the qualifiers here and in the answer below, of course.)

Comment: Also, incidentally; I already searched, and there is currently no one on Stack Overflow named SomeArbitraryUser!

Comment: @AndrewBarber Snarf it up quick ! LOL

Comment: @HowardPautz Users can have duplicate names on SO. so one person using the name doesn't prohibit anyone else from using it.

Comment: What @Servy says is true. [And yet, I did it anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2788622/somearbitraryuser)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it would be inappropriate, we would not have that possibility to directly contact a user in this case. It is fine in your case.

It would be not if you tried to get in contact with a certain user in order to just chat with him. To privatly contact a user you can look up his profile for personal contact information. If a user does not provide those then limit the contact to the related posts.

Comment: +1 Interesting - wasn't even thinking about the 'direct contact' mechanism. The 'ping' request would add to the running content, if the user pinged decided to reply. I suppose if I happened coincidentally to be in chat at the same time that user was, I might ask him or her to post more in the thread, but I don't think I'd 'hunt down' a user to chat about it (unless all heck was breaking loose for some reason :)) ... I'm gonna leave this one open for a while longer, @ juergen , to see what others might say. thx.